# call a URL, from a multipage Dash app in a new tab/browser

Tags: python-3.x, callback, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

Dear Stackoverflow Members

I am currently looking for ways to call a `link or URL` within a `multipage Dash app`, and look suggestions with regards to the definition of the `callback`.

**Initial Thought:**

```
#html.Div('old', style= {'display':'inline-block', 'float':'left'}), html.Div(dcc.Link(daq.BooleanSwitch(id='test-switch', on=False, style= {'display':'inline-block', 'float':'left', 'margin-left': '1px'}), href='/testURL')),
```

**Callback definition:**

```
@app.callback(
Output('boolean-switch-output-1', 'children'),
Input('test-switch', 'on')
)

def render_url(flag):
  if flag == True:
      return '/testURL' # fails in calling /testURL
```

- where `/testURL` has successfully been defined in `testURL.py` through:

  ```
  register_page(__name__, path='/testURL')
  ```

**N.B:** In the meantime, I am using as a workaround:

```
html.Div('old', style= {'display':'inline-block', 'float':'left'}), html.Div(html.A(daq.BooleanSwitch(id='test-switch', on=False, style= {'display':'inline-block', 'float':'left', 'margin-left': '1px'}), href='/testURL', target='_blank'))
```

Thanks in advance for your clarification.

Answer (score 0):

My solution has eventually consisted of adding a `function.js` within the

**Clientside Callback :**

```
app.clientside_callback(
"""
function(val) {
    if (val === true) {
       return window.open('/testURL', '_blank').focus();    
    }   else {
        //pass
    }
}
""",
Output('boolean-switch-output-1', 'children'),
Input('test-switch', 'on')
)
```

**N.B:** *Hope It would help someone facing similar challenges.*

Best